# "No, you must" vs "No, you must be" as a response to "You must be an idiot"

Tags: word-usage, sentence-choice

Let's say someone said, **"You must be an idiot"** to me to mean that I'm most likely an idiot. As a response to that, can I say these sentences below interchangeably to mean that that person is actually most likely an idiot himself?

- **"No, you must."**
- **"No, you must be."**

I think the the latter is correct, but the first one somewhat sounds wrong to me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In conversation, you can omit the verb, or verb phrase, after "must" when replying to a statement containing "must". This applies whether the modal verb 'must' is being used to express necessity...

You must work harder - No, you must [work harder].
You must leave now - No, you must [leave now].
We must run faster - No, you must [run faster].

...or when it is being used to express probability, or an opinion:

You must be an idiot - No, you must [be an idiot].

Comment: Thank you. Does "No, you must be" sound bad to you?

Comment: It sounds like normal conversation. You must or you must be, both equally OK.

Comment: I actually have some other questions on this subject, but I'm going to open another topic for it.